# Vuetify firebase image upload 'watch' not firing

Tags: firebase, vue.js, file-upload, vuetify.js

I am trying to upload an image to firebase and store the resulted URL in an array as well as update a progress bar.

The image is uploading fine and making to to my firebase UI however I can t seem to get my Vue watcher to fire and store the URL into the array.

I have placed the example into a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-o336v?file=/src/App.vue). Be grateful if someone could spot my mistake

```
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"firebase": "^7.15.1",
"moment": "^2.26.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-router": "^3.2.0",
"vue-uuid": "^2.0.2",
"vuetify": "^2.2.11",
"vuex": "^3.4.0",
"vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Vue does not allow adding new root-level properties to the data object
> after the initialization of a component.Since Vue performs the
> getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a
> property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to
> convert it and make it reactive.
> [Vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

In your component you need to set default value of `uploadTask`:

```
  data() {
    return {
      uploadTask: null,
   }
}
```

Or you can use `Vue.set()` method, which is less clean approach in this case.

Comment: My my, a simple over sight of core Vue functions left me confused for a couple days :( 

Thanks David

Comment: I have  follow up question, the same example is uploading the 3 items but the watch takes only seems to be retuning one single URL. 

would you have an idea what would b e wrong?